# Shiro session creation flooding

Tags: shiro

I notice that even as an anonymous user, a shiro session is created (and inserted into my db in my case) at my first access to a web page. After a successful login, the session record is simply updated with the appropriate attributes.

Now i tried 'stress-testing' the main page url with :

```
curl -s "http://myapp.com?[1-1000]"
```

And my fear came true as i count the created session is as much as the loop.

So the question here is, is there anyway i can avoid having a session creation flood by a web crawler or a spammer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, where allowing session creation only upon login, yayy :

```
/login = authc
/logout = noSessionCreation, logout
/** = noSessionCreation, anon
```

Comment: I find it suspect that you awarded the answer to yourself after I gave the answer that allowed you to write your code sample :(

Comment: @LesHazlewood: Hi author. Just want to clear up that my answer is 2 days earlier from your answer. The answers in SO are not sorted by date, so that might cause the mis-assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution will throw an exception (as expected) if a developer (or software framework/library) attempts to create a session on those pages.  This is generally a 'good thing' as it will expose unexpected session usage during development, ensuring that developers (or web frameworks that you use) do not create sessions when they're not supposed to.

If you're using JSPs, you'll also likely want to set

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

At the top of the JSP to ensure that Tag Libraries or the Servlet Container itself do not attempt to use sessions (you'd be surprised to see how often this happens without your knowledge).

Comment: I am sorry that i forgot to mention that i am using a custom and native session, so its not affected by the web sessions. And luckily that in this case i am using freemarker instead of JSP. Thank you.

Comment: @AlbertKam sounds good - so yes, I think using the `noSessionCreation` filter in your case is the best way to go.